# Кладёт код из ASCII таблицы вместо числового значения

Tags: c, массивы, стек

Смысл моей задачи состоит в том, чтобы реализовать обратную польскую нотацию с использованием массива (который служит как стек).
Проблема: Я считываю строку посимвольно. Если символ - число, то я кладу его в стек. У меня кладётся не само значение, а его номер из таблицы ASCII. Как это исправить?
Спасибо за помощь!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100000
int A[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
int top = 0;

void push(char x)
{
    A[top] = x;
    top++;
}

int pop()
{
    top--;
    return A[top];
}

int isEmpty()
{
    return top == 0;
}

int isNumber(char x)
{
    if(x >= '0' && x <= '9')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int isOperation(char x)
{
    if(x == '*' || x == '+' || x == '-')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int result(char str[])
{
    int i, res = 0, operat = 0, temp = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if(isNumber(str[i])) {
            push(str[i]);
        }
        else if(isOperation(str[i])) {
            if(isEmpty())
                return 0;
            else if(top == 1) {
                temp = pop();
                return temp;
            }
            else {
                operat = str[i];
                int x1 = pop();
                int x2 = pop();
                if(operat == '+') {
                    res = x1 + x2;
                    push(res);
                }
                else if(operat == '*') {
                    res = x1 * x2;
                    push(res);
                }
                else if(operat == '-') {
                    res = x1 - x2;
                    push(res);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    int ores = pop();
    return ores;
    }

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    gets(str);
    printf("%d", result(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isNumber()

Не нужно изобретать велосипедов: [man isdigit](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=isdigit&category=3).

> Если символ - число

Может быть не число, а цифра?

> У меня кладётся не само значение, а его номер из таблицы ASCII

В стек кладётся **символ** (то есть именно его числовое представление) - ровно то, что вы и делаете вот этим кодом: `A[top] = x;` Если нужно положить значение, то для одной цифры достаточно такого:

```
A[top] = x - '0';
```

Что аналогично коду:

```
A[top] = x - 48; // 48 - код символа '0'
```

Если в x находится, скажем, символ '5', то получится:

```
A[top] = '5' - 48;
// или
A[top] = 53 - 48; // 53 - код символа '5'
// оно же:
A[top] = 5;
```